# ¿Publicar mismo sitio en diferentes proyectos firebase hosting?

Tags: firebase

Hay forma de configurar el comando `firebase deploy` de tal forma que publique mi sitio en un proyecto u otro que tenga en firebase?

Vi en un articulo que se podia configurar el archivo `.firebaserc` algo así

```
{
  "projects": {
    "pruebas": "app-pruebas", //El ID del proyecto que tiene el sitio y BD de pruebas
    "produccion": "app-produccion", //El ID del proyecto que tiene el sitio y BD de producción
  }
}
```

Lo intento, pero al usar el comando `firebase deploy` esperaba que me indicara qué proyecto quería publicar o algo, pero me arroja un error de lectura del archivo `.firebaserc` y lo publica en el primer proyecto que encuentra.

Mi archivo `firebase.json` es tal cual como se creó

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  }
}
```

No modifiqué nada más.

¿Alguien me podria ayudar a cómo hacer ese despliegue en diferentes proyectos de firebase?.

Entiendo que tendria que hacer un `npm run build`por cada `firebase deploy` que quiera hacer dado que tengo que cambiar las key para que se conecte a cada sitio, o algo así, si me pueden ayudar, estaria agradecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el `.firebaserc` solo agregue los dos proyectos que voy a usar.

Luego en el `cmd` hay que ejecutar el comando `firebase use <alias project>`, en este caso usar `firebase use produccion` o `firebase use pruebas` y listo, ya luego puedo hacer el `firebase deploy` a ese proyecto.

Claro, vale aclarar que hay que hacer el respectivo `npm run build` antes de publicar en otros ambientes cuando se cambian las configuraciones de Firebase, pero pues es lo normal.

Answer (score 1):

Espero que esta respuesta no sea tarde y que le pueda servir a alguien.
En el file firebase.json duplique el hosting, o sea, con los nombre de los hosting a los que quiero hacer el deploy, por ejemplo:

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "site": "hosting1",
      "public": "dist/proyecto", //aqui va el build(cambiar por el nombre real)
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "site": "hosting2",
      "public": "dist/proyecto", //aqui va el build(cambiar por el nombre real)
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Luego deployas con el siguiente comando:

- firebase deploy --only hosting:hosting1 --project nombre del proyecto1
- firebase deploy --only hosting:hosting2 --project nombre del proyecto2